# GitHub Action "Host key verification failed"

Tags: github-actions, cicd

Hope you are doing well .. I am new to CI/CD and implementing via GitHub Actions. I followed steps and having an issue on deployment. I am getting this error

```
Run ssh -p 2200 ***@*** "cd *** && git checkout *** && git pull && exit"
Host key verification failed.
Error: Process completed with exit code 255.
```

and my ymal file is

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  run_pull:
    name: run pull
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: connect and pull
      run: ssh -p 2200 ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}@${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }} "cd ${{ secrets.WORK_DIR }} && git checkout ${{ secrets.MAIN_BRANCH }} && git pull && exit"
```

I generated the SSH key and added into authorized_keys, i get **GitHub Fingureprints** from https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints and add them to known_host. but still getting this error.

Any clue, am i doing something wrong or missing something ? thanks in advance.

PS: I want to deploy a PHP script to Server via SSH

Comment: look at https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27716

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem.

One of root causes was missed rec in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

After fix, all works for me with next config

```
name: Deploy lending to Server

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main  # Adjust this if you're using a different branch

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Set up SSH key
      uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.9.0
      with:
        ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

    - name: Deploy via SSH
      run: |
        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }} ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}@${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }} "mkdir -p /var/www/kokyangwuti/landing"
```